# how to use getNeighbors function on DirectedSparseGraph of JUNG?

Tags: java, netbeans, graph, netbeans-8, jung

Is there anyone who can give an example of how to use the getNeighbors function of the DirectedSparseGraph implementation of JUNG (http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/DirectedSparseGraph.html). The following is the explanation of the function, but does not give any example of how to actually use the function to retrieve the neighbouring nodes of a vertex.

```
public Collection<V> getNeighbors(V vertex)
{
    if (!containsVertex(vertex))
        return null;

    Collection<V> neighbors = new HashSet<V>();
    neighbors.addAll(getPreds_internal(vertex));
    neighbors.addAll(getSuccs_internal(vertex));
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(neighbors);
}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
theGraph.getVertices().stream().forEach((v) -> {
    Collection<V> neighbors = theGraph.getNeighbors(v);
});
```

But immediately NetBeans pointed out that "cannot find symbol V". What class should I import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`V` is a generic type specifier for the nodes in the graph.  If your nodes are `String` objects, for example--that is, if the node type for `theGraph` is `String`--then you would in this case replace `V` with String.

You may want to check out this tutorial on generics: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html